# Quotient field extension for an incomplete DVR

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, nt.number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $R$ be a DVR with maximal ideal $xR$, and assume that $R$ is not complete in the $xR$-adic topology. Let $\hat{R}$ be the completion of $R$ in the $xR$-adic topology. Set $K=Q(R)$, the fraction field of $R$, and set $K'=Q(\hat{R})$. Must the degree of the field extension $K'/K$ be infinite? The answer is "yes" for all the examples that I know, and it feels like it should be true in general, but I don't see it in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nagata's example (E3.3) shows that you can have $[K':K]=p<\infty$. Thanks to Bruce Olberding for the pointer.

Comment: Sorry for digging up a very old question, but could you point to a reference?